# How can I get the path of a remote service executable?

Tags: c#, service, .net-3.5

I have a WCF service and a client that talks to it.  These can be on any machine(s) on the network.

What I want is for my client application to be able to determine the location of the executable of that WCF service, regardless of where it is.  Specifically, the path one would see using Services.msc.

Searching SO led to a few options for when everything is on the same machine, but I need to know how to get that path when they are not on the same machine.

**Addendum:**
I am considering that the service itself needs to simply be asked and answer.  Seems obvious.  As I stated in a comment...I'm asking on the off chance that someone knows how to get this purely from the client side.  If it's protected, secured, outright disallowed...so be it.

Comment: The physical file path? You realise the security implications if this was inherently supported in any way?

Comment: @GrantThomas Yes, I do.  And I'm asking this with the assumption that someone will tell me "hell no, and don't even try it".  But on the outside chance there is a way...I ask.